# Is a verb important in any English sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is a verb exists in any English sentence? If yes, what is the verb in the following sentence?

> In a democrat government there are separate authorities which are the executive, the legislation and judicial.

Comment: Could you identify the verb in *Children are happy*?

Comment: If verbs are not important in any language, how would you think what way they can communicate with each other?

Comment: I do not see a reason to close this (except possibly for citing no research). It is on the topic of English. It is admittedly poor English, but that can be expected from people who are struggling to learn English. It is clear that what is being asked is whether a verb must be present in a proper English sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a verb is very important. The verb here is “are” (a form of the verb “to be”):

> In a democrat government there **are** separate authorities which are the
>   executive, the legislation and judicial.

I would have constructed this sentence differently by the way, if this is your intended meaning:

> In a democrat**ic** government there are separate authorities,
>   **namely** the executive, legislat**ive** and judicial authorities.

Comment: Thanks. So where is the subject and object?

Comment: In Arabic language there is a nominal and verbal sentence.

Comment: The nominal sentence in Arabic language starts with noun and no need for verb.

Comment: And in verbal the sentence starts with verb and no need for noun.

Comment: Those forms do not exist in English. Every complete grammatical sentence must contain a verb and a noun or pronoun as subject. However, there are dummy subjects, namely "there are" and "it is."